# Why can't I attach files and images on my SharePoint list using Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I am working on a system that takes information form an email and adds it to a SharePoint list.
I am using MS power automate to grab the mail info and add it to the SharePoint list.
It works with plain text, and links, but not with text styles.
But for some reason I cannot transfer pictures and attachments, and then open them from the list.
I am using a shared mailbox, setup by my company for this.

Se mere detail her.
[Flow setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhyeY.png)
[SharePoint setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMtWk.png)

I tried converting it all to HTML and then adding it to the SharePoint list, to see if it is a formatting issue.
But I did not get any wiser on the problem.

I also tried looking a deferent approach, where I convert the e-mail to a PDF and then add the PDF file to the list.
But that is a complete restructuring, and I want to make sour that this is not just a small thing I haven't seen.
Before I change the setup completely

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
I overlooked a trigger setting.
It should be set to Yes
And then it works.
[Flow setting set to Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZyWb.png)